# How to make htaccess not redirect to http on form submission

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

Part of my .htaccess file forces `https` on certain pages (e.g. when user logs in, enters credit card information, etc.) while forcing `http` on all other pages. This seems to be the ideal setup for what I need.

However, one of my site's extensions is responsible for generating a credit card processing form. In the form's action url, it has the `https` url of the web root in it (e.g. https://domain.com/). However, the web root is not one of those pages that the .htaccess forces `https` on, thus it's forcing a redirect to `http`. Because of this, the extension is failing because the form is attempting to submit to an `https` that redirects to `http`.

What should I do? I don't want users being forced to view a secured page when they don't have to; I'd rather they reap the benefits of caching. And obviously, on secured pages, they need to submit to secured URLs (my site's CMS apparently works in such a way that all form submissions to the web root works just fine). I can't tell the extension to submit to a different URL.

Here's the relevant part of my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Define default protocol for all assets
   RewriteRule ^ - [E=protocol:http,E=ssl:%{HTTPS}off]

   # Define HTTPS targets, add more cond as required
   RewriteCond $1 (payment|sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) - [E=protocol:https,E=ssl:%{HTTPS}on]

   # Rewrite host if necessary and redirect on correct protocol
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:protocol}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # Protocol switch if necessary (host is already correct)
   RewriteCond %{ENV:ssl} ^(onoff|offon)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:protocol}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # Finally, process the internal redirect
   RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Maybe this could be modified to "don't redirect if it's a form submission?"

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion your optimizing the wrong thing by strictly forcing certain pages to use HTTPS and other to use plain HTTP. Simply redirect everything to HTTPS and be done with it.

The [computational cost of HTTPS](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch04.html#TLS_COMPUTATIONAL_COSTS) is negligible in most cases. 
Your concern about browser cache with SSL [seems unfounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https) as well.

And my pet peeve: you're better off including your configuration in the main httpd.conf instead of relying on .htaccess files, according to [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: +1, you beat me to it.  I'm definitely a proponent of the 'encryption everywhere' ethos.  But at the very least, respect the wishes of your end users if they want to use SSL, and don't force them unencrypted.  So a happy medium is to force encryption where you need it, and do nothing where you don't.

Comment: I'm more of the opinion that the majority of users don't care either way and simply type the least and enter example.com in the address bar without any protocol specification leaving it to the site operator to upgrade to SSL. You have a point that making that more optional is not necessarily a bad thing, but the opposite, forcing users away from the TLS does seem like a bad idea.

Comment: @HBruijn - my concern about caching does not have to do with browser caching. I expect that to work with HTTPS. However, HTTPS won't work with public proxy caching, though -- right? I'm not concerned about the minuscule computational cost of HTTPS; I'm concerned about public proxy caching. And I agree with you about httpd.conf.

Comment: @ChristopherKarel - "So a happy medium is to force encryption where you need it, and do nothing where you don't." <-- isn't that what I am doing already?

Comment: Actually - I'm going to be using a CDN. Maybe public proxy server caching won't matter as much if my resources (style sheets, JS, images) are being served via CDN?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I have no idea of how prevalent caching proxy servers are nowadays (maybe a good question in itself) and if taking those in account makes sense. E.G. Facebook sends all static contents over HTTPS too. The old standby is subdomain for static content and ensuring new filenames are used for updated static content and the modern alternative is CDN.

Comment: In the interim, how would I modify this .htaccess so that it doesn't redirect to http on POST? I just realized that POST variables are not retained on redirect, which is probably the reason for my problems.

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a "best practice" solution for forcing HTTPS on everything? I've seen so many approaches to this on the net. Not sure what are the pros and cons of each approach. Suggestions?

Comment: I force global SSL via:  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`.  But as with anything Apache, there's 50 other ways to do it.

Comment: @ChristopherKarel - which parts of my htaccess can I safely remove and replace with that?

Comment: Almost all of the first four sections.  =)  It appears you have a part that removes the `www.` subdomain from your requests, as part of the third rule block.  That one will need some intelligent rewriting to still rewrite the host, without the SSL tricks.  The rest all appears to be fancy logic to determine what needs HTTP vs HTTPS.

Comment: Right. I don't want the "www". I also don't want "index.php". I'll need to play with your suggestion to see if I can make it work right.